# Find the Minimum column value with group by in mysql

Tags: mysql

Harshit is a Social Worker Who Wonders around the world.
Here is a Record of his all trip Recommended by different organization with expenses in form of trip table.
[image: Trip Table]

I just Want to print entries for all the countries Harshit has visited with the minimum Expense.

I have tried The group by operator as described below.
[image: Tried for minimun Expense Trip]

here I am not getting the entry of minimum expense in case of country=IND

My Required Data is :

[image: Required Result]

Can Anyone Please Help me to find out the mysql query for desired result.

Comment: No pictures thanks. Instead, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Instead of pictures, just copy the text from your command line and put here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the full row having minimum expense amount per country.

- First, you need to determine the minimum expense value per country using [Group By with Min()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) function, in a derived table `t3`.
- Do a join with the [derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), **using** country and the expense value, to get the row with minimum expense value, per country.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT t.*   
FROM trip AS t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.country, MIN(t2.expense) AS min_expense 
            FROM trip AS t2 
            GROUP BY t2.country) AS t3 
  ON t3.min_expense = t.expense 
     AND t3.country = t.country
```